# Grid tilt effect like Windows 8 Start Screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a tile in WPF that looks like the tiles of the Windows 8 Start screen.
Actually, the problem is that I don't know how to make the tilt effect of the Windows 8 tiles ( the click effect ).
I tried different transformations such as matrix transofmration, but this is not what I want.

Explanation in image :

[image]

Default style:

[image: Default style]

Here is my code

```
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                        <MatrixTransform>
                            <MatrixTransform.Matrix >
                                <Matrix OffsetX="5" OffsetY="5" M11="1" M12="0.1"></Matrix></MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                        </MatrixTransform>
                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MaCollectivitéWPF;component/src/Img/Home/Porte Document-petite.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" >

                        </ImageBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
```

It's almost what I want but I only want the bottom to be tilted.

I've take a look at the 3D controls but I think it's to complicated for what I'm looking for.

Is there a solution with Layout Transformation I would not have seen yet ?

Comment: On this website, you need to show what you have tried (in code) and highlight what problems you had. You're more likely to get help if you follow the guides in the [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Thank you for your advice . I edited my post in consequent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to pinch [Greg Schechter's Planerator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx) for tilting.

Your use case is exactly the one in the article, so I doubt you'd need to change anything. I've not tried it myself, but it seems to reduce tilting the plane to fairly easy xaml. Worth a look at least.

```
 <pl:Planerator RotationY="35">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ... >
            <StackPanel>
                <Label  FontSize="24" Content=" " Foreground="#FF000000"/>
                <Border ... >
                    <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" />
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox ... />
        </StackPanel>
    </pl:Planerator>
```

[image: Tilted plane. I think it's okay to use this image.]